# Angular 7 - Global HTTP Interceptor for whole Application

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular7, angular-http-interceptors

In my `app.module.ts`, I registered an HTTP Interceptor like this:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

However, requests made from a lazy-loaded module don't use the Interceptor.
It only works when registering the HTTP Interceptor in the lazy-loaded module, too.

**But I want to provide it only once in the `app.module.ts`.**

Any ideas on how to do this? Or do I have to provide it in every module?

Comment: Try using `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` when declaring your interceptor, and remove it from the providers section

Comment: doesn't work... when removing from provider, how  should angular know, that its an interceptor?

Comment: Make sure you're not importing HttpClientModule in your lazy modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening in your case is something similar that can be observed from [**this GitHub thread**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575) as well. JB Nizet is also probably referring to the same thing in his comment.

You most probably have added the `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your `LazilyLoadedModule`. Hence it's not using the InterceptorService. To make it work, just get rid of it from there. Once that is done, it will use the global HTTP Interceptor Service.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-interceptor-working-for-lazy-loaded-module?file=src/app/core/token-interceptor.service.ts) for your ref.